# Can I automatically set "Editable" to False for read-only notebooks?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I know that notebooks have an `"Editable"` option that is accessible via the option inspector or by calling, say,

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], "Editable" -> False]
```

I have some notebook files that I do not want to modify (not even re-evaluate things). I have set these files to `read-only` via the file system. This attribute is respected by most text editors: when the file is opened, it is presented as not editable. In Mathematica, however, I can modify the document freely. Saving it just has no effect and after closing and reopening it, the changes will be lost.

I would prefer Mathematica to automatically set Editable to False for read-only notebooks on opening. How would I do that?

It would be good if I did not have to open the files, modify the Editable attribute and save them again. I might want to make them editable again later easily by just removing the read-only attribute in the file-system.

If possible, I would also like to disable evaluation in these notebooks (looks like that is still possible with Editable set to False).